# Getting Bad Request from graphql call

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I am  using the vue-apollo with VueJs. Upon clicking the I trigger the 'query' function which makes the graphql api call but i always get a bad request response.

Please tell me what am I missing? Thank you in advance.

This is my apollo client:

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/cache';

let apolloClient :any;

export function createApolloClient() {
  if (apolloClient) {
    return apolloClient;
  }

  return apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
      fetchOptions: {
      mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
  }
  }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
}
```

Here is how I am consuming it:

```
const result = ref(null);

async function query() {
 
  const apolloClient = createApolloClient();

  try {
          const queryResult = await apolloClient.query({
        
          query: gql`
          query Parcel($ownerZipcode: String) {
              Parcel(Owner_Zipcode: $ownerZipcode) {
                PIN
                Owner_Name
                Owner_Zipcode
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: {
            parcelId: "7657574gg"
          }
        });
        console.log('queryResult is ',JSON.stringify(queryResult));
        result.value = queryResult.data;
    
       
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
})
</script>

<template> 
    <button @click="query">Button</button>
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: please edit the question to include the full error as seen in console and/or network tab of your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Looks like your graphql server isn't running, try hitting the endpoint in your graphql playfround or in postman to rule out any issues there. 

Other possibilities could be CORS etc.

Comment: Looks like you defined a variable in your query as ```$ownerZipcode```, but you are passing  ```parcelId: "7657574gg"``` with your request, either pass ```ownerZipcode``` or change the variable name to ```$parcelId```. Which ever one you use in your resolver

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I used the Vue js Options API instead and it worked for some reason.